# Get file via paramiko sftp in python and store to local variable?

Tags: python, csv, sftp, paramiko

I am using paramiko library in python. I'm trying to download a csv file and store it in a local variable that I Can then use to modify and work with.

(I have it making the desired modifications already in a separate python file when I assign the local csv path manually - so that's all good)

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname='xxx', port='xx', username='xxx',
               password='xxx', allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)

curFile = ''
sftp = client.open_sftp()
sftp.put('MP4088.csv', 'AJTESTFILE.csv')
print(sftp.getfo('AJTESTFILE.csv', fl='curFile', callback=None, prefetch=True))
with sftp.open('AJTESTFILE.csv', 'rb') as fl:
        df = pd.read_csv(fl, sep=' ')
sftp.close()
```

I am able to upload files with put, and get downloads them locally, but how do I store it in a variable to work with? (Say, a variable titled "CurFile")

If interested in my other code for whatever reason, this is it:

```
import csv

new_rows = []  # a holder for our modified rows when we make them
changes = {   # a dictionary of changes to make, find 'key' substitue with 'value'
    'vehicle_id': 'stock number',  # I assume both 'key' and 'value' are strings
    'vin': 'vehicle_id',
}

with open('MP4088.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)  # pass the file to our csv reader
    for row in reader:     # iterate over the rows in the file
        new_row = row      # at first, just copy the row
        for key, value in changes.items():  # iterate over 'changes' dictionary
            new_row = [x.replace(key, value)
                       for x in new_row]  # make the substitutions
        new_rows.append(new_row)  # add the modified rows

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    # Overwrite the old file with the modified rows
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(new_rows)

    print("done!")
    print(writer.)
```

(Ultimately, once I get it downloading and making the modifications correctly I will be using the google sheets api to upload the updated file to a google sheet)

My question: How do I store the received file locally?

Comment: You already have code that downloads the CSV, parses it and stores the results to a variable: `with sftp.open('AJTESTFILE.csv', 'rb') as fl:` + `df = pd.read_csv(fl, sep=' ')` – what's wrong about it?

Comment: @martinPrikryl AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: I'm trying to store it into a variable named "CurFile"